# How to Create XML with Multiple Root Element

Tags: c#, xml

Following XML in my needed Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<units> 
    <unit>
        <unit-info xmlns="">
            <unit-id>4550669</unit-id>
            <order-id>11949776</order-id>
            <parcel-id>none</parcel-id>
            <supplier-id>6</supplier-id>
        </unit-info>
    </unit>
</units>
```

for that I used following C# code:

```
   XDocument Document = new XDocument();
   XDeclaration declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
   Document.Declaration = declaration;
   XNamespace ns = "http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani";
   XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
   XNamespace ce = "http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/common";

   XElement nameSpaceElement = new XElement(
            ns + "units", new XAttribute("xmlns", ns), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi), new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ce", ce), new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation",
    "http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ani/ani512-input-CAR.xsd"),Document.Root);

   Document.Add(nameSpaceElement);
   XElement uniType = new XElement("unit", new XAttribute("type", "ARTICLE"));

   Document.Root.Add(uniType);

   XElement unitInfo = new XElement("unit-info", new XElement("unit-id", "4550669"), new XElement("order-id", "11949776"), new XElement("parcel-id", "none"), new XElement("supplier-id", "6"), new XElement("timestamp", DateTime.Now));
   Document.Root.Add(unitInfo);
   Document.Save("document.txt");
```

But I got an output like following document

```
<units>
  <unit></unit>
   <unit-info xmlns="">
    <unit-id>4550669</unit-id>
    <order-id>11949776</order-id>
    <parcel-id>none</parcel-id>
    <supplier-id>6</supplier-id>
    </unit-info>
 </units>
```

Here my second element closed there itself. But I need to close that element as before root element.

How to get my out using `XDocument` and `XElement`.

Comment: Instead of `Document.Root.Add(unitInfo);` do `uniType.Add(unitInfo);`

Comment: Yes i got the answer

Comment: XML does not support multiple root elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your unitInfo to uniType, not directly to the root.

something like uniType.Add(unitInfo) instead of
Document.Root.Add (unitInfo)